# Download documents with Google Drive android SDK as PDF

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

i work on project that requires integration with Google Drive and build on top of PDF file format.

As i see there is a way to open various native documents from Google Drive as PDF trough 'exportLink' function as it described there https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads

but i cannot find anything like that for android SDK, is this functionality available for android?

And if so, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Google Drive Android API does not support exportLink. You could use the web API in your android application.